# php7 область видимости

Tags: php7

На html странице открываю php тег , переменные объявленные в одной блоке тегов не видны в другом. На php 5.6 такой проблемы нет. У меня стоит nginx+php-fpm, linux mint

Comment: покажите наглядно.... тобишь код.. ошибки какие есть? включите error_reporting

Comment: <? $a='Ivan'?> Hello<?=$a> Переменная  $a не объявлена

Comment: не включены шорт теги...... php.ini -> short_open_tag=On

Comment: short_open_tag...<?php $a='Ivan'?> Hello<?=$a> работает

Comment: `<?=` с версии 5.4 всегда включена и не зависит от short_open_tag ....... поэтому надо посмотреть ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С PHP 5.4.0, специальный короткий тег `<?=` доступен всегда, а вот обычные короткие теги `<?` необходимо включать директивой `short_open_tag=On`

Поэтому код

```
<? $a='Ivan'?>
```

НЕ выполняется. То есть переменной $a ничего не присваивается.

А код

```
<?=$a ?>
```

уже выполняется, и честно нам отвечает, что переменная не задана

Также стоит заметить, что использование коротких тегов  `<? ?>` не рекомендовано, поскольку далеко не везде они разрешены и код, соответственно, сильно теряет в переносимости.

Comment: `<?=$a>` это не правильно правильно так `<?=$a ?>`

Comment: @Naumov да, у автора скопировал, не обратив внимания. спасибо